# Node not able to read environment variables in AWS Beanstalk

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, environment-variables, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I can't go into details unfortunately, but I'll try to be as thorough as possible. My company is using AWS Beanstalk to deploy one of our node services. We have an environment property through the AWS configuration dashborad, the key ENV_NAME pointing to the value in this case one of our domains.

According to the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_nodejs.container.html), and another [resource](https://alexdisler.com/2016/03/26/nodejs-environment-variables-elastic-beanstalk-aws/) I found once you plug your variables in you should be able to access it through process.env.ENV_NAME. However, nothing is coming out.  The names are correct, and even process.env is logging out an empty Object.

The documentation seems straight forward enough, and the other guide as well. Is anyone aware of any extra steps between setting the key value pair in the dashboard, and console logging out the value once the application is running in the browser?

Comment: What's running in EB? Is the node app running in a docker image?

Comment: The node app is running. Edit: Sorry, we're just uploading a zipped up node application.

Comment: What I'm asking is, are you deploying a docker image that has a node app in it? Or are you using a linux distribution in EB to host the node app? What is the node app running on?

Comment: It is running on a standard Amazon linux distribution.

Comment: Do you deploy your app using the CLI? If so, are you including a section in the deploy script that specifies/overwrites the env vars? Just throwing out ideas here.

Comment: I'm not apart of the deployment process unfortunately, so my knowledge of that is limited. I can tell you we're uploading a zip file through the AWS UI. And we're not having to rewrite any of the environmental properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I'm an idiot. We were referencing the environment variable in the JavaScript that was being sent to the client. So, we were never looking for the env variable until after it was off the server. We've added a new route to fetch this in response.

Comment: If I had a nickel for every time the answers to one of my problems was "I'm an idiot," I wouldn't need to work anymore -_-